# Bean Validation on method

Tags: java, jsf, bean-validation

```
public class Register {
    @NotNull private String password;
    @NotNull private String passwordRepeat;
    @AssertTrue private boolean comparePasswords() { 
       return password.equals(passwordRepeat);
    }

    private Set<ConstraintViolation<Register>> violations;

    public void doRegister(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        violations = validator.validate(this);

        if(violations.isEmpty()) {
            // This occurs
        }
    }
}
```

My validation will pass if both my passwords are not null, but they are different.
Seems like the last constraint will not be taken into account, though I do not have a clue why. Does anyone have suggestion?

And no, I am not searching for any implementations of @Matches or simular custom validators. I just would like to get this problem solved.

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

I have run some tests regarding this, hopefully the results will provide needed information.

*Bean.java*

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
    @NotNull private String example1;
    @NotNull private String example2;
    @AssertTrue private boolean examplesMatch() { return example1.equals(example2); }

    private Set<ConstraintViolation<Bean>> violations;
    private FacesContext context;
    private Validator validator;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

        example1 = "abc";
        example2 = "def";
        runValidation(false, 1);

        example1 = "abc";
        example2 = "abc";
        runValidation(true, 2);

        example1 = "abc";
        example2 = null;
        runValidation(false, 3);
    }

    private void runValidation(boolean assertion, int testNr) {
        FacesMessage message;
        violations = validator.validate(this);
        if(violations.isEmpty() == assertion) {
            message = new FacesMessage("Passed test nr. " + testNr);
        }
        else {
            message = new FacesMessage("Failed test nr. " + testNr);
        }
        context.addMessage(FacesMessage.FACES_MESSAGES, message);
    }
```

*index.xhtml*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        #{bean}
        <h:messages />
    </body>
</html>
```

*Result*

```
beanvalidation.Bean@31c5c3da

    Failed test nr. 1
    Passed test nr. 2
    Passed test nr. 3
```

Comment: Why use annotations. just have the boolean method , inside which you can have the null check, then inside the null check compare the two strings .

Comment: what validation mode are you using?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Because this is just a relevant sample of a larger class.

Comment: @nate_weldon I have no ValidationMode defined, so I guess it will default to AUTO?
I am currently implementing it using Validator validator = Validations.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator; violations = validator.validate(this);

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*examplesMatch()* is not a valid [Java Beans](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) boolean property getter. It needs to start with *get* or *is*.

Comment: in addition to `is` and `get`, starting the method with `has` also appears to work.

Comment: This answer is still relevant in 2023; crazy the documentation doesn't reflect this in a top level place around `AssertTrue`

Answer (score 0):

@BalusC gives a great answer as usual!

Note also: in this brave new world of the `jakarta.validation` namespace versus `javax.validation`, in my case I was importing `AssertTrue` from the former but my container (WildFly 26) was only recognising the latter.