# Why @AssertTrue doesn't work while @NotNull works?

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm working on a entity library. I put some bean-validation annotations on my Entities.

I strongly believe a bean-validation implementation in on the class path.
`@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` works and `@javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue` doesn't work.

```
class MyEntity {

    @AssertTrue // does't work
    public boolean hey() {
        return false;
    }

    @NotNull // works; violation while persist
    private String some;
}
```

What possibly did I do wrong with it?

I uses `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator` and changing it with `org.apache.bval:bval-jsr` doesn't make any difference.

**UPDATE**

The method is actually invoked. I check the log.

Here comes my method.

```
@AssertTrue(message = "a property must be eclusively system or owned")
private boolean execlusivelySystemOrOwned() {
    logger.info("execlusivelySystemOrOwnded()");
    final boolean result = system ^ (getOwner() != null);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "result: {0}", result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @NeilStockton `AccessType.FIELD`, I believe.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950573/330457

I had to rename the method to `isExeclusivelySystemOrOwned`.

That's why it's called **Bean**-Validation.

Comment: *still relevant in 2023. I can confirm that the mentioned answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950573/330457 also worked for me. Wild.

Comment: `hasExeclusivelySystemOrOwned` works as well.

Comment: @ValerijDobler Are you sure?